# ¿Evitar mostrar el nombre del id en la url al dar click en el menu scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Para evitar que se cargue el `id` del `menu` de navegación en la `url` cambie los atributos de: `href="#"` por los atributos de: `data-ref="#"` funciona eso pensé, porque no se agrega el `id` del según el `menú` al presionar... Pero al llegar al reposo de la animación automáticamente me agrega el `id` del `menu` en la `url`.

Código:

```js
$(function() {
  $("[data-ref^='#']").bind('click', function(e) {
  //$('a[href*=#]').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr("data-ref");
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 600, function() {
      location.hash = target;
    });
    return false;
  });
});
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollDistance = $(window).scrollTop();

  // Show/hide menu on scroll
  //if (scrollDistance >= 850) {
  //  $('nav').fadeIn("fast");
  //} else {
  //  $('nav').fadeOut("fast");
  //}

  // Assign active class to nav links while scolling
  $('.page-section').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).position().top <= scrollDistance) {
      $('.navigation a.active').removeClass('active');
      $('.navigation a').eq(i).addClass('active');
    }
  });
}).scroll();
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  transition: all .1s ease;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 64px;
}
.page-section {
  height: 480px;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 35%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  padding: 3em;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #43cea2 10%, #185a9d 90%);
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.navigation {
  position: fixed;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  background-color: #999;
  color: #fff;
}
.navigation__link {
  display: block;
  color: #ddd;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.navigation__link:hover {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
.navigation__link.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<nav class="navigation" id="mainNav">
  <a class="navigation__link" data-ref="#aaa">Section 1</a>
  <a class="navigation__link" data-ref="#bbb">Section 2</a>
  <a class="navigation__link" data-ref="#ccc">Section 3</a>
  <a class="navigation__link" data-ref="#ddd">Section 4</a>
  <a class="navigation__link" data-ref="#eee">Section 5</a>
  <a class="navigation__link" data-ref="#fff">Section 6</a>
</nav>

<div class="page-section hero" id="1">
  <h1>Smooth scroll, fixed jump menu with active class</h1>
</div>
<div class="page-section" id="aaa">
  <h1>Section Two</h1>
</div>
<div class="page-section" id="bbb">
  <h1>Section Three</h1>
</div>
<div class="page-section" id="ccc">
  <h1>Section Four</h1>
</div>
<div class="page-section" id="ddd">
  <h1>Section Five</h1>
</div>
<div class="page-section" id="eee">
  <h1>Section Six</h1>
</div>
<div class="page-section" id="fff">
  <h1>Section Seven</h1>
</div>
```

¿Cómo puedo evitar que se agregue el `id` del `menu` de navegación en la `url` al reposar la animación?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Tengo una solución al problema que estas solicitando:

Lo que quieres es que **no te aparezca el #... en la url** cuando se hace click a los botones para el campo URL:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el código solo tienes que comentar la linea:

```
location.hash = target;
```

Quedando la rutina de esta forma:

```
$(function() {
    $("[data-ref^='#']").bind('click', function(e) {
    //$('a[href*=#]').bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr("data-ref");
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
        }, 600, function() {
            // location.hash = target;
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**Explicacion:**

El `location.hash` sirve para poner o asignar el URL de ancla, mas información sobre este comando en este link:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp

Al final el código al ejecutarlo no te colocara el `#...` en la URL quedando como lo requieres:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Otra cosa** que puedes agregar para mejorar el código es una regla CSS como esta:  `cursor: context-menu;` para que el puntero del *mouse* sea una flecha al apuntar sobre los link, quedaría muy bien en el código:

```
.navigation__link {
  display: block;
  color: #ddd;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  /*  puntero cursos */
  cursor: context-menu;
}
```

Espero que pueda ayudarte..

Comment: Aquí esta la solución, denle a este hombre la recompensa...

Comment: gracias por el apoyo!

Comment: @AlexanderRodriguez Gracias funciona tal como lo deseaba :)

Answer (score -2):

comenta la línea

```
location.hash = target;
```